# php extended class not inheriting parents current property values

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm fairly new to classes. I can't understand why my extend class won't inherit it's parent properties, as their set. It seems to inherit properties at their constructor value.

What is the correct way to ensure the current values are inherited?

```
class Form {

    public $data = array();
    public $TheValue;

    public function __construct($data) {  
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function UpdateTheValue($x){
        $this->TheValue = $x;
    }
}

class FormField extends Form {

    public function __construct() {  
        parent::__construct();
    }

}

$data = array(1,2,3);
$Form = new Form($data);
$Form->UpdateTheValue('the value should be this');
$FormField = new FormField();
```

and this is the result of $FormField

```
FormField Object
(
    [TheValue] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        )

)
```

as you can see TheValue is empty.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not inheriting the parent value as you've created a new instance... if you were to simply create the `FormField` in the first place you could set the value with `$FormField->UpdateTheValue(...)` Oddly though, I'm not sure why it's not throwing a warning about required parameters since `new FormField();` is effectively calling `new Form()` without any `$data` (which should be required)

Comment: Thank you. I need to call Form beforehand in the script. and later, depending on the situation, introduce FormField. So I'm wonder how to keep the set values from Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `FormField` extends  the `Form` class, not **an instance** of the `Form` class.

If it worked the way you assume, what do you think that should happen if there are 2 instances of the `Form` class?

```
$dataA = array(1,2,3);
$formA = new Form($dataA);
$formA->UpdateTheValue('A');

$dataB = array(1,2,3);
$formB = new Form($dataB);
$formB->UpdateTheValue('B');

$formField = new FormField();
```

In your example you should be creating an instance of the `FormField` class which has all the properties of its parent:

```
class Form {
    public $data = array();
    public $TheValue;

    public function __construct($data) {  
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function UpdateTheValue($x){
        $this->TheValue = $x;
    }
}

class FormField extends Form {}

$data = array(1,2,3);
$formField = new FormField($data);
$formField->UpdateTheValue('the value should be this');
```

But then of course, **why would a "form field" extend a "form" to have its properties?** These are clearly two different entities which serve two different purposes.

I can only speculate that what you are actually trying to achieve is similar to this:

```
<?php
class Form {
    private $fields = array();

    public function __construct($fields) {
        $this->fields = $fields;
    }

    public function updateField($index, $value) {
        $this->fields[$index]->setValue($value);
    }
}

class FormField {
  private $value;

  public function __construct($value) {
    $this->setValue($value);
  }

  public function setValue($value) {
    $this->value = $value;
  }
}

$fields = array(
  new FormField('A'),
  new FormField('B'),
);

$form = new Form($fields);
var_dump($form);

$form->updateField(0, 'AAA');
$form->updateField(1, 'BBB');
var_dump($form);
```

Comment: @DarkBee: Possibly but that is beyond the scope of my answer. I'm restricting my answer to trying to explain difference between a class and an object.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Does that mean I can't define Form beforehand? I would like to Call $Form>New Form(); and later define the FormField?

Comment: You can and you are defining `Form` which is a **class**. `$Form` on the other hand is an **object**, an instance of the `Form` class. You can have only one definition of a class (in one namespace) but many instances of this class.

Comment: Ok, so If I define $Form beforehand. Later I define a $FormField object, how will the variables from $Form be passed to $FormField? As In your code above $FormField is defined (there is no $Form). I apologise for my lack of understanding and appreciate your help.

Comment: It's really not easy to know what and how you are trying to build whatever it is that you are building but I made my guess with some extra code.

Comment: Thank you very much for making it clear, it appears my lack of understanding how classes work in general was holding me back. I'm creating a simple form builder, using the Form class to hold the core data (id, form name etc) and then employing the FormField extended class to store and update data for a specific field.

Comment: Yes, Dave, start with the basics of object-oriented programming. I think there is lots of good resources, be it a book or an online tutorial which might explain it to you better than I did. :-)

Comment: I'd probably key-index the fields in the form (associative array) and throw in magic setters and getters but yup - looks like a solid starting point :)